# I am trying to get some data from a server using Retrofit . But I cant find where's my code is going wrong

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to fetch some data from a server using Retrofit but there is something wrong with my code but I cant find it myself.

```
package com.example.shobkhana.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;   
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.shobkhana.Activity.MainActivity;
import com.example.shobkhana.Model.Fooddata;
import com.example.shobkhana.Model.Popular;
import com.example.shobkhana.R;   
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects; 
import retrofit2.Callback;

public class PopularAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularAdapter.PopularViewHolder> {

    private  Context context;
    private List<Popular>popularlist;


    public PopularAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Popular> popularlist) {
        this.context =context;
        this.popularlist = popularlist;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PopularAdapter.PopularViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.popular,parent,false);

        return new PopularViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PopularAdapter.PopularViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.poptext.setText(popularlist.get(position).getName());
        Glide.with(context).load(popularlist.get(position)).into(holder.popimg);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return popularlist.size();
    }

    public class PopularViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView poptext;
        ImageView popimg;

        public PopularViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            popimg=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            poptext=itemView.findViewById(R.id.poptext);
        }
    }
}
```

**Mainactivity**

```
    package com.example.shobkhana.Activity;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import com.example.shobkhana.Adapter.PopularAdapter;
    import com.example.shobkhana.Model.Fooddata;
    import com.example.shobkhana.Model.Popular;
    import com.example.shobkhana.R;
    import com.example.shobkhana.Retrofit.ApiInterface;
    import com.example.shobkhana.Retrofit.Client;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.Callback;
    import retrofit2.Response;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
        ApiInterface apiInterface;
        RecyclerView poprecycler;
        PopularAdapter popularAdapter;
        List<Popular>popularList;
    

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            apiInterface= Client.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<List<Fooddata>> call=apiInterface.getAlldata();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Fooddata>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Fooddata>> call, Response<List<Fooddata>> response) {
    
                    List<Fooddata> fooddataList=response.body();
                    getPopulardata(fooddataList.get(0).getPopular());
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Fooddata>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server not responding",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                }
            });
        }
    
   private void getPopulardata(List<Popular>popularList){
    
          poprecycler=findViewById(R.id.poprecycle);
          popularAdapter=new PopularAdapter(this,popularList);
          RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
          poprecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
          poprecycler.setAdapter(popularAdapter);

          }    
    }
```

When I try to run this I get this...

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.shobkhana.Activity.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:51)
```

Answer (score 0):

The list that you are getting on `onResponse` is empty list

> fooddataList.get(0).getPopular()

That is why when you try to get first object of `fooddataList` it thows null pointer exception. So, make sure you are getting a non-empty list.

Comment: the error he got `java.lang.Object java.util.List.get (int)null object reference` but if the list is empty it throws this exception `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index : 0, Size: 0`

Comment: @ShayKin how should i code it then?